# cloth sewing is bouncing and not sewing up but bouncing like the picture below

Tags: physics

cloth sewing is bouncing and not sewing up but bouncing like the picture below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try reducing the "Object collision" and "Self collision" Distance values a lot (something like 0.001, or even 0.0001, its relative to the subdivision level of the mesh: the more dense, the lower the values).

Comment: it's getting worse... check the updated image

Comment: i dint check the normals it works now ...